# Procedimiento almacenado en laravel con parametro

Tags: sql, sql-server, laravel, stored-procedure

He visto dos sintaxis al llamar procedimientos almacenados que reciben parametros en laravel, ambas funcionan perfectamente:

```
//Concatenando parametro    
DB::select('exec Miprocedimiento "'.$parametro.'"');

//Utilizando ?
DB::select('exec Miprocedimiento ?', array($parametro));
```

¿Cual es la forma correcta?, ¿existe alguna diferencia en cuanto a rendimiento, seguridad?

Comment: La primera opción faltaría los paréntesis antes de concatenar el valor ?

Comment: Ambas funcionan estimado @Dev.Joel lo que quisiera saber si existe diferencia en cuanto a seguridad, rendimiento, o son exactamente iguales

Comment: Probó las dos opciones ? Sería bueno añadir la etiqueta SQL :)

Comment: Si las dos las probé, gracias por la sugerencia, ya agregue las etiquetas

Comment: La segunda opción es mas segura, para evitar ataques de inyección sql

Comment: Que raro he intentado ejecutar un procedimiento que utiliza un parámetro y ambas no funciona.

Comment: Que sintaxis usas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En cuanto a rendimiento, ambas opciones son equivalentes.

Pero no en cuanto a seguridad.

De manera general, al escribir *comandos* a ser interpretados por el motor de base de datos, se deben tomar precauciones para evitar ataques de parte de los usuarios de una aplicación, por ejemplo, la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Para ello, es preferible utilizar, siempre que se pueda, parámetros, y no concatenar textos, menos textos introducidos por el usuario, como parte de una sentencia SQL (no solo para ejecutar procedimientos almacenados, sino en general).

Por esto, la **segunda forma** que incluyes en tu pregunta, es más recomendable que la primera.

```
DB::select('exec Miprocedimiento ?', array($parametro));
```

Pues el texto que el motor interpretará, será solamente `'exec Miprocedimiento ?'`, quedando explicitamente definido que el valor de `$parametro` debe luego pasarse de manera integra al invocar `Miprocedimiento`.

En cambio, con la primera opción:

```
DB::select('exec Miprocedimiento "'.$parametro.'"');
```

Existe el riesgo, por ejemplo, si el usuario lograse manipular la variable `$parametro` para que tenga el texto:

```
123'; drop Tabla; select '
```

El texto que el motor recibirá, que es producto de la concatenación, será:

```
exec Miprocedimiento '123'; drop Tabla; select ''
```

Existe el riesgo que esto termine destruyendo información en la base de datos.

Hay rutinas para *sanitizar* el texto introducido por el usuario, pero eso nunca será tan efectivo como el uso de parámetros.

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::select("exec Miprocedimiento :parametro",array( 'parametro'=>$parametro ));
```

En Caso de que quieras hacerlo de esta forma:

```
DB::select('exec Miprocedimiento "'.$parametro.'"');
```

Podrias usar las dobles comillas de esta manera

```
DB::select("exec Miprocedimiento $parametro");
```

Para no concatenar .. aunque no es recomendable hacerlo de esta manera porque estas vulnerables a los ataques de inyeccion sql ..  lo correcto es

```
DB::select("exec Miprocedimiento :parametro",$parametro);
```

pero si tu procedimiento tiene mas de 2 parametros lo recomendable es esto

```
DB::select("exec Miprocedimiento :parametro",array( 'parametro'=>$parametro ));
```

Answer (score -1):

es más recomendable que la primera.

```
DB::select('exec Miprocedimiento ?', array($parametro));
```

Comment: Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: puedes aclarar porque es mas recomendable?